# Panels don't render views in separate blocks

Tags: 7, views, panels

Steps:

1. I have a view, it has 4 different blocks.
2. I wanted to have one page that would include those 4 view blocks.
3. So I created custom Panels page, added views.

Problem I ran into is that for some reason Panels shows all 4 view blocks inside one view instance, so views content from different views blocks are all smashed into views row inside same one view.

I expected it would show view blocks as separate blocks in their own separate containers, so I could wrap them up and give each view different title, but now all of them are smashed into one view and I don't understand why.

4 separate view blocks in the panels layout (so should render in separate wrappers/containers each?):
[image]

Under `view-content` from multiple views blocks, the content is all smashed into each `view-row` that fall under one same wrapper. Why are they not separate? Why each view block doesn't have separate container/view? Why all of them fall under `view-display-id-block_2`? Block_2 is just one of the view blocks of that same view, it also has block_3 and block_4, why and how all of them fall inside block_2?

[image]

Comment: Are you using content panes instead of blocks inside the view? You have to enable that as an extra module I think.

Comment: @NiallMurphy Can you post this as answer, because that's exactly what I needed, to use `Content pane` inside Views and not `Block`

Comment: I can't really post it as a useful answer without some extra details.. And I'm lazy. I'm glad it worked out and these comments will be here for anyone in the future. You can post it as a self-answer if you like so it's closed properly.